# What do these abbreviations mean? נ''י & מו''ה

Tags: hebrew, translation, acronyms

I am filling out an authorization form for medical treatment. I am not 100% on what the abbreviations **נ''י**    &    **מו''ה** & mean.

**זֶה לאשׁר בי **מו''ה****  (מורי וחמי?)   ______ **נ''י** (נרו יאיר?)
_____________________________**בתובת**

My translation: **This is confirmation for (NAME?) _______ (MY HE HAVE A LONG LIFE?) in the area of **MEDICAL TREATMENT**___ .**

Comment: מורי הרב או מורנו הרב.   ונרו יאיר

Comment: You should really confirm any details with the office you are providing the form to and/or your lawyer to make sure you understand what you are authorizing.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Usually the point of these forms is to make sure the hospital/doctor knows to follow halacha, so you select a Rav to be consulted and his decisions followed. So here מו"ה would be מורי הרב, which is a common way for one to refer to their Rav. נ"י is נרו יאיר, as you guessed.